# Adding separator in UICollectionViewCell like one in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing an app in which I need " a separator line " after each row of `UICollectionViewCell`...(like in `UITableView` after each row).

Anyone having idea how to get this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Create a UIView with a black background that is 1 pixel high and 320 pixels wide?

**For Example**

***For Horizontal Line***

```
UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x cordinate,y cordinate,1,linelenth)];
horizontalLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:horizontalLine];
[horizontalLine release];
```

***For Vertical Line***

```
UIView *verticalLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x cordinate,y cordinate,linelenth,1)];
verticalLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:verticalLine];
[verticalLine release];
```

Comment: Yeah It worked...but if I want this after every row as my collection view array increases..then How can i Reuse it?? Thanks.